Error: @actions/artifact v2.0.0+, upload-artifact@v4+ and download-artifact@v4+ are not currently supported on GHES
I am executing my github  pipeline and getting this error on run test

(Error: @actions/artifact v2.0.0+, upload-artifact@v4+ and download-artifact@v4+ are not currently supported on GHES)

This is my workflow
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, master ]
jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: 22.11.0
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: Install Playwright Browsers
      run: npx playwright install --with-deps
    - name: Run Playwright tests
      run: npm  test
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      if: always()
      with:
        name: Reports
        path: test-results/
        retention-days: 30

-I am expecting the test to run succesfully

upload-artifact@v4 and download-artifact@v4 are currrently not supported on GHES. There is a mention to this on their GitHub repository: GitHub: upload-artifacts - What's new
It is a petty because at the same time they are announcing the shutdown of v3 on public GitHub. Also, Dependabot on GHES is suggesting to upgrade to v4 which will break your workflow (as you are seeing).
You can, at least in theory, track the status of artifacts v4 here: https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/930
However, this issue was recently closed because GitHub cleaned up their roadmap. v4 support was originally planned for Q4 this year and then moved to Q1 next year. As of writing this post it isn't on the timeline at all anymore.
I assume the only possibility at this point is to make sure enough GHES customers speak to their GitHub representatives to push them to support artifacts v4 in GHES soon.

Thank you so much for this detailed info, you suggest I should just remove it from my yaml workflow?

@lungelozondo For now, you have to stick to v3 instead of v4. You don't have to remove it entirely. If the answer suits you, please accept it.
